# Autocomplete not working in some condtion

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces autocomplete component with itemtip option,
after getting suggestions I am selectiing one value as a example lastname,
but I want to display in textbox both lastname and firstname of player, so tried in this way.

`itemLabel="#{p.lastName} #{p.firstName} "` having some space with these two .

```
<p:autoComplete id="watermark" value="#{backingBean.object}"
                            size="40" completeMethod="#{backingBean.completeholder}"
                            var="p" 
                            itemLabel="#{p.lastName} #{p.firstName} " itemValue="#{p}" converter="player">
                            <f:facet name="itemtip">
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="cellsp-panel">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <p:graphicImage value="#{p.imagePath}" width="60"
                                            height="60" />
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <h:outputText value="LastName " style="font-weight:bold" />
                                    <h:outputText id="ln" value="#{p.lastName}" />

                                    <h:outputText value="FirstName " style="font-weight:bold" />
                                    <h:outputText id="fn" value="#{p.firstName}" />


                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="e,c">
                            </p:ajax>

                        </p:autoComplete>
```

so after selecting a suggestion, it displays lastname and firstname of player perfectly.
But one problem is created as - it creates a space in autocomplete textbox, so i need to use 
backspace to remove this space so that I can search a for getting suggestions.
How can I overcome from this problem?

1. Also I am using watermark on autocomplete , it works only when I use single itemLabel like
   itemLabel="#{p.lastName} otherwise it unable to display watermark in autocomplete.

3.Also when I use for no-case sensitive input so that user can search without case sensitive,
once I get any suggestions and still if try to type some keyworks for further filterations, 
suggestions disappears,it works if I go for case sensitive by default way.

1. User can type players lastname or firstname , and still he needs to gets suggestion ,what modifications should I need to done in following method ? 
   I have stored lastname with First letter as a Capital, so I am using toUpperCase() in this way

   public List completePlayer(String query) {
           List suggestions = new ArrayList();

   ```
       for(Player p : players) {  
           if(p.getlastName().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))  
               suggestions.add(p);  
       }  

       return suggestions;  
   }
   ```

How can I overcome from this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your player compare is resolving to this:
Smith.startsWith("S") -> true
Smith.startsWith("SM") -> false

What you want is:

```
if(p.getlastName().toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
```

The space in your autocomplete is coming from this line:

```
itemLabel="#{p.lastName} #{p.firstName} " itemValue="#{p}" converter="player">
```

You have a space after  #{p.firstName} in itemLabel before your closing quote.
As for the watermark, I don't know. I have never tried it with an autocomplete. Can you include your p:watermark tag so we can see what it is referencing?

Comment: I have removed space between itemlabel, now I have tried it in this way.
itemLabel="#{p.lastName} #{p.firstName}" itemValue="#{p}" converter="player"> 

but still it  it creates a space in autocomplete textbox, 
so we need to use backspace to remove this space.This space is now coming due to there is space 
between   #{p.lastName} and #{p.firstName}"  .And actually i need to mauntain space between lastname
and firstname after selecting suggestion.

So still how can we remove this pace/?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what your problem is. Because the LastName and FirstName are blank when the page renders, it puts only the space in that field. The easiest solution I can think of is to add FullName getters and setters to your backing bean and do the name aggregation there instead of on the front end. Then you will be able to control when/if the space is added.